# How to prevent navigation when navigating away from a component for React Native - web

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, blur, react-native-navigation, react-native-web

I have a component with a form in it and I would like to prevent the user from navigating away if the form is dirty (while also providing a pop up). Right now I have implemented the solution provided by react-navigation, however, it only works when the component is leaving the state, not on blur.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/

My project has many quick links that navigate you within the current stack and across other stacks. When the user clicks one of those links, the current component does not unmount and therefore, 'beforeRemove' event listener is not triggered. Is there a solution to cover this case? How can I prevent the user from navigating on 'blur' or when the component wants to 'unfocus'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`beforeRemove` event call when user is leaving the screen.

Try `blur` event which is emitted when the screen goes out of focus.

checkout : [Navigation Events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

Comment: Blur won't let you prevent default behaviour/navigation, all i can do is do some logic if the component blurs. There may be a way with the useFocusEffect hook but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: What if you navigate back to that screen which is just blur? 

Comment: The screen will navigate then the pop up will occur

Comment: you can show global popup (having state in redux) which will show above all screen. so if you even move out of that screen you can show pop up and from behind you can go back to that prev. screen. make sense?